# Angular 2 edit cart total after remove a product

Tags: function, angular, components

i'm stucked on a problem and i don't know how to get out of it.
I have two component sibiling:

One that show a list of products with a button for each product that delete from the cart the single product with a POST call at one REST API.

And another component that simple call a REST API for get the totals of the cart and show it.

The problem is that when i delete correctly the item from the cart, obviously the cart total doesn't update itself.

So, i've searched on the communities and i think that there are two different solutions:

- Use a shared service;
- Use @Input and @Output

I've tried using the first option, but without success, i tried also with @input and @Output but i don't think that i really understand how to use it between two components that aren't Parent > Child or opposite.

What i need is to call the function **GetTotals** inside the **CARTTOTAL.COMPONENT** from the **CARTITEMS.COMPONENT** for updating the prices.

I've tried to inject the same service in both components and call the function from the first one, but seems doesn't work.

Here the code:

**cartitems.component.ts**

```typescript
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, Output } from '@angular/core';

import { ManageGuestCartService } from '../manageCartServices/addtoguestcart.service';
//import { CarttotalComponent } from '../carttotal/carttotal.component';

// Service for guest total cart
import { TotalguestcartService } from '../manageCartServices/totalguestcart.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-cartitems',
  templateUrl: './cartitems.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cartitems.component.css'],
  providers: [ManageGuestCartService, TotalguestcartService]
})

export class CartitemsComponent implements OnInit {

 itemofcart:any[];

  constructor(private _guestcartservice: ManageGuestCartService, private _totalguestcart: TotalguestcartService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.listCartItems();
  }

  listCartItems() {

    return this._guestcartservice.getCartDetails()
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.itemofcart = data;
            //console.log(this.itemofcart); 
        },
      (err) => {
        //alert('vuoto'); 
      });

  }


  removeProductFromCart(itemid) {
      return this._guestcartservice.deleteProductFromCart(itemid)
      .subscribe(data => {
      //  this.itemofcart = data;
       // console.log(this.itemofcart); 
       this.listCartItems();
       this._totalguestcart.getTotals();
      },
      (err) => {
        alert('errore');
      });
  }

}
```

**carttotals.component.ts**

```typescript
import { Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

// Service for guest total cart
import { TotalguestcartService } from '../manageCartServices/totalguestcart.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-carttotal',
  templateUrl: './carttotal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./carttotal.component.css'],
  providers: [TotalguestcartService]
})
export class CarttotalComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _totalguestcart: TotalguestcartService) { }

   totals:any[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.retrieveTotals();
  }

  retrieveTotals() {
    return this._totalguestcart.getTotals()
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.totals = data;
        console.log(this.totals);
        },
      (err) => {
        alert(err); 
      });
  }

}
```

**totalguestcart.service.ts**

```typescript
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class TotalguestcartService {

  constructor(public http: Http) { }



    public getTotals() {
        let cartid;
                cartid = localStorage.getItem("guestCartId");

                let contentHeaders = new Headers();
                contentHeaders.append('Accept', 'application/json');
                contentHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

                return this.http.get(URL, { headers: contentHeaders})
                //.map(res => res.json())
                  .map((res) => {
                        if(res.status == 404) {
                          return res.status;
                        } else {
                          return res.json();
                        }
                    });
    }

}
```

Can someone give me the correct way to find a solution to this issue? all the feeds are accepted :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can call `getTotals` from `CarttotalComponent`, why didn’t it work from `CartitemsComponent`? What kind of error occurred?

Comment: I don't know, maybe when i was calling like this  **this._totalguestcart.getTotals();**  in the removeProductFromCart function, i did some errors, but for sure the gettotals function doesn't fire.

Comment: Please add the error at the end of your question, thanks.

Comment: No error is displayed on the console!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, you need to mark your providers in the module, so that you share the same service between your components.

Shared Service would be best here. From my understanding you want to fire an event in the `carttotals` component, when deleting an item in the `cartitems` component.

Well we can set up Observable which will fire that event. So in your `totalguestcart` service add this:

```
private fireEvent = new Subject<boolean>();

event = this.fireEvent.asObservable();

emitEvent(bool: boolean) {
  this.fireEvent.next(bool);
}
```

Here we are just using boolean values, as you do not need to pass any specific values, but only fire an event.

Then when you are performing the deletion, let's notify the other component, which subscribes to this, that the method should be fired.

```
removeProductFromCart(itemid) {
  return this._guestcartservice.deleteProductFromCart(itemid)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.itemofcart = data;
      this.listCartItems();
      this._totalguestcart.emitEvent(true); // add this!! 
    },
    (err) => {
      alert('error');
    });
 }
```

And in your cart totals, subscribe to this in your constructor, and execute the `getTotals` method:

```
constructor(private _totalguestcart: TotalguestcartService) { 
  _totalguestcart.event.subscribe(res => {
      this.retrieveTotals();
  })
}
```

`this.retrieveTotals` will then be fired each time you are deleting an item. Of course this can be used in other methods as well, like adding and updating (if you need it).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! this work for me! after deleting the product, the total function being fired!

Comment: Great! Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Throw out the service `TotalguestcartService` out of the providers of your components and put it into the providers of the app-module: What is happening: each component is getting a local copy of the service, so they cannot exchange information, as there are TWO services injected. Putting it global (app.module) provides it for every component as long as the component doesn't do an own provider.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! ok, after i remove from the providers the service, and add to app-module, what i have to insert in the constructor? if i delete _totalguestcart from the constructor, how do i call the function? thanks in advance!

Comment: The constructor stays the same, only the injection from the provider has to leave.

Comment: So, i've deleted only the providers but seems that anything change. no errors

Comment: I would keep the data within that service, which is now shared between both sibling components. and with the update/deletion update your data structure in the service. you may put the data array public, so you can use  _totalguestcart.data (or what ever you call it) directly in your component.